# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor how to cancel scheduled threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a web app which runs an interface for controlling an irrigation system. The system starts up to 10 or so threads, using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

I have found that when I close down the server, many of these threads continue to run. From the Tomcat catalina.out log:

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [GH2] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

The classes that start these threads are dotted around my app. In order to try to have some control over stopping them, I have a single ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor created by a ServletContextListener and passed into each of the classes that might start a task.

I have tried setting properties in the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor that I assumed would close down all threads when contextDestroyed() is called in the listener:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        executor = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
        executor.setContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
        executor.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
        executor.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("executor", executor);
```

Here is a typical bit of code that schedules a thread:

```
public WeatherScheduler(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
        checkEveryHour();
    }

    public void checkEveryHour() {
        final Runnable weatherChecker = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!Thread.interrupted()) {

                    if (Date_TimeUtils.isBetween7amAnd8pm()) {
                        weather = new Weather();
                        weather.getNewForecast();
                        IrrigationLogger.getInstance().logEvent("weather forecast: " + weather.toString());
                    } else
                        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "weatherChecker not called as isBetween7amAnd8pm() == false ");
                }
            }
        };
        // delay of a minute to allow for getting internet connection, repeat every hour
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(weatherChecker, 1, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
```

When the server is closed down, the contextDestroyed() method is called in the listener, and I have

```
executor.shutdownNow();
```

included in that method.

But still I get the message in the log file that threads have been started that can't be stopped.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your threads are handling interrupts ok. What about including [awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) ?

Answer (score 0):

The way any ThreadExecutor tries to stop a currently running thread is by setting interrupt flag by invoking `Thread` class method `interrupt()` on that thread. It is responsibility of the running thread to detect that it was "asked" to finish, so the running thread should clean up and terminate once the signal received. So first in your runner code surround it with try-catch where you will catch `InterruptedException` and also in your runner code you suppose to invoke method `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and if it returns true clean up and finish the thread (same as in your catch statement)

Comment: The run() method is called just once an hour. I have some code that checks whether an interrupt has been called on that thread, but the thread might stay running for up to an hour until the run() method is called. Most of my threads are like this. I was expecting to be able to end them all through some call in the executor, but this seems like wishful thinking.

Comment: The executor can only send a request for thread to stop, it is the responsibility of a thread to detect the request and stop. So if your run method runs for an hour it must be some loop there. Put in the loop the check fore interrupted flag. That's the right way

Comment: That run method doesn't run for an hour. It runs once each hour, and only take a couple of seconds to complete. I have other threads that run briefly once in 24 hours, so I don't see how putting a loop in the run method to look for an interrupt will cancel the thread. It might stick around for 24 hours till its run method is called. That's the scenario I'm trying to work around.

Comment: Having come across this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8269467, I think I'll leave my code as it is, and just reboot the Raspberry Pi every 24 hours - using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ! That'll stop the threads piling up!